# how to get second column by some simple cut or awk command after uniq -c option

Tags: shell, sorting, awk, cut, uniq

I used following command on a file with 10 columns:

```
cut -f3 f1.tsv | sort | uniq -c | sort -k1,1 -nr > f2.tsv
```

which gave me a file like:

```
   1230 ABC
   1059 DEF
    846 GHI
    845 JKL
```

but now for some other work, i need just the second column.

So please tell me how can i use some simple, awk or cut command to get it.

Comment: `man cut`, then read the examples at the bottom.

Comment: so i could use something like: cut -c9-100 f2.tsv. But i will have to check "9" always and also how to know "100" if line is too big.

Comment: @Ed, I know how simple it is to get desired output from f1.tsv. The thing is that i need it from f2.tsv. Because of some reasons the information i have is just f2.tsv and I explained how it has been generated. And now i need desired output from f2.tsv only.

Comment: Sorry Ed.. But it was not for wasting the time.. i thought it other way around. I thought it will give reference, and most probably people must be using such commands frequently, so they will quickly respond.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need of those continues commands and pipes. Post some sample contents of f1.tsv and the final desired output.